# Azure Pipeline: dotnet publish fails - assets.json doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1/win-x64'

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-pipelines

I have a .NetCore 3.1 commandline app. When buidling locally and publishing, it works completely fine using below commandline

`dotnet publish -c dev -r win-x64 --self-contained true`

In the Azure pipeline - I had to do the `dotnet restore` before doing a publish using the above command. Whilst publishing I had to add extra param `--no-restore`, as per Microsoft's recommendation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#publish) as I have private nuget feeds.
`dotnet publish -c dev -r win-x64 --self-contained true --no-restore`

> Most dotnet commands, including build, publish, and test include an
> implicit restore step. This will fail against authenticated feeds,
> even if you ran a successful dotnet restore in an earlier step,
> because the earlier step will have cleaned up the credentials it used.
>
> To fix this issue, add the --no-restore flag to the Arguments textbox.

Now, the publish part of the pipeline has started failing with the error -

*C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'MyProject\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1/win-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.*

Am not using a publish xml, but specifying all the arguments as shown above in the command line. I've checked the csproj has the target framework specified

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;dev;test;pre;prod</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Need any pointers as to what might be going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: did you try adding `<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>`?

Comment: I guess the operation systems of your machine and the pipeline are different.

You do as mentioned in the error message:

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;dev;test;pre;prod</Configurations>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

And please check your PlatformTarget.
e.g.:

  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>

Comment: @MarkusMeyer - that worked! if you want to add that as an answer, i'll mark it as accepted! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please add RuntimeIdentifier as mentioned in the error message:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;dev;test;pre;prod</Configurations>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Please also check PlatformTarget.

```
 <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
```

I guess the local machine has a different OS than the build agent.